# Verifying Deployment for Windows 7 ESU

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, deployment, verification

I am a bit confused about the meaning of "Verifying your deployment on eligible Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, and Windows Server 2008 machines for ESU" in this set of instructions:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/how-to-get-extended-security-updates-for-eligible-windows/ba-p/917807

I have already verified that the License Status in Windows Script Host was set to "Licensed" via slmgr /dlv.  What does additionally verifying the deployment accomplish, and is it necessary to make sure the ESU acquisition process was successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have already verified that the License Status in Windows Script Host was set to "Licensed" via slmgr /dlv.

The installation not only must be licensed for the operating system it's Activation ID must match that of the ESU program you are eligible for.

> What does additionally verifying the deployment accomplish, and is it necessary to make sure the ESU acquisition process was successful?

**The only requirement is to properly activate your ESU eligibility.**  This of course requires specific patches.  However, if the system administrator chooses not to verify the status of the system, that is entirely their choice.

> I am a bit confused about the meaning of "Verifying your deployment on eligible Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, and Windows Server 2008 machines for ESU"

These are instructions for those Administrators that don't already know the process.